# Java JTextField text length not updating after deleting characters

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield, string-length

I am trying to create a JTextField with a key listener that will enable a button only when the length of the text is exactly 4.

It's working but if length of 4 is reached, and I delete a character (using backspace or delete buttons) the text length isn't updated and keeps being 4, until I remove another character, but that will make it actually 2 characters.

Can you help me with the code to make it update the length? Thanks in advance.

I already tried these **without success**:

```
Document doc = field.getDocument();
if (doc.getLength() > 0) {
    try {
        doc.remove(field.getCaretPosition(), 1);
    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
    }
}
```

and

```
field.setText(field.getText().substring(0, field.getText().length()));
```

Comment: I can't tell from your code snippet, but you have to put a DocumentListener on the Document underlying the JTextField.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc why would I need it? I mean, is it the only way? ... If so, can you share a basic code snippet of its implementation, please? Thanks

Comment: [How to Write a Document Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks although I found a fix, and already answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error:

I was calling the method to enable the button in the `KeyListener`'s `keyTyped` method, instead of doing it in `keyReleased` method.

That simple change, made the code work as expected.

Comment: The better solution is to use the DocumentListener. The KeyListener is an old API for AWT. Swing has a newer and better API that doesn't depend on KeyEvents.